# Can't download from Update Manager or Software Center

Tags: software-center, update-manager

I am new to Linux so please bear with me, I have 12.04 installed, when I am trying to download from **Ubuntu Software Center** or if I try to check for updates via **Update Manager**, I get this message:

> **Requires installation of untrusted packages.**

and there are two buttons: **OK** and **Repair**. If I click **OK**, it does nothing, but if I click **Repair** then I get this message:

> **Failed to download repository information.**

then I click on **OK** to close the message box then this message appears:

> **Check Internet connection.**

Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: some screenshot would be nice

Comment: Is your internet connection working fine for other applications?

Answer (score 2):

Do you have an active internet connecting? Check your connecting 1st and ensure it's working properly.Then open Ubuntu software centre and cancel if any repair window pop-up.

Go to

> Edit > Software Source

in **Ubuntu software** Tab select

> **Download From** to **Main Server**

Then Close Everything. Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> to open a terminal. Type

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get upgrade`

if `upgrade` failed then try with these

`sudo apt-get -f install`

Answer (score 1):

Nice suggestion:

"Edit" -> "Software Sources", in "Ubuntu software" tab select "Download From to Main Server". Then close everything, press Ctrl+Alt+T to open a terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

If upgrade failed then try with these:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to clean apt cache and software center cache:

```
sudo apt-get clean
```